# Overflow: content on left side is hiding on overflow is set to auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, overflow

I am trying to show a [box of content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL8yT.png) as same as in computer and mobile by using fixed width and overflow

```css
:root {
    --box: rgb(20, 33, 150);
    --box1: rgb(55, 75, 255);
    --background: rgb(147, 158, 255);
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: var(--background);
}

.squad-table>.col-12 {
    border: 2px solid var(--background);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
}


.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper>.row {
    width: 500px;
    margin:3px; 
}


.box {
    background-color: var(--box);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.squad-box {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: var(--box1);


}

.count-box {
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    background-color: var(--box1);

}


.team-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.team-box-inner {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--box);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Learn HTML</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row test">
            <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
                <h1 class=" display-1 text-center">Squad</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row squad-table">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="wrapper">

                    <div class="row box text-center">
                        <div class="col-4 count-box">Team 1</div>
                        <div class="col-8 space-box">space</div>
                        <div class="col-12 squad-box">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row box text-center">
                        <div class="col-4 count-box">Team 1</div>
                        <div class="col-8 space-box">space</div>
                        <div class="col-12 squad-box">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 team-box">
                                    <div class="team-box-inner">name</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>



    <!-- JS files -->
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

The problem here is the overflow which is hiding a slice of content on left side when the screen size is less than 1000px which is bizarre and I am not understanding what's happening.

Is it because of bootstrap, flex, or overflow ?

Note: I used bootstrap 4.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just chage this

```
.squad-table>.col-12 {
    border: 2px solid var(--background);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Because its start center. You change position left.